# Politically correct wording for error causes

Tags: jira, itil

I am currently making some adjustments to our ticketing system.
When the helpdesk closes an issue they have to select what the root cause was.
For example a ticket might be created where the user thinks there is something wrong with the product but actually he was not using it properly.
I am now looking for politically correct wording of such root causes.
Is there a general definition for something like that or some kind of guideline?
The following I would like to include:

- Human failure
- Training issue
- Bad design
- Poor maintenance
- Bad quality

Any input is appreciated!
Cheers.

Comment: Interesting question indeed, although I would call it "non-judgemental" rather non "politically correct". Some questions: What do you exactly mean by "bad quality"? Bad quality of what? Same for "bad design": Bad design of what?

Comment: "Bad quality" would refer to a part of the physical product (part breaks under certain load), "Bad design" means that it is not used as expected or not ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to offer the following *Error Source Assessment Choices* for the user to choose from:

- **Human behavior** = what you call *Human failure*
- **Missing or misleading education** = what you termed *Training issue*
- **Material failure** = physical product breaks under certain load, aka *Bad quality*
- **Product not fit to purpose** = product probably not used as expected by the designers, aka *Bad design*
- **Maintenance cycle too long** = product is not taken care enough, what you call *Poor maintenance*
- **Algorithm needs fine-tuning** = the logic behind the IT part of your product behaves unexpected, for those guys and girls who question any number on a display.

I suggest to add the latter point since nearly all (physical) products nowadays come with a software side, even it is only the calibration of the temperature measured by a small resistor.

Answer (score 1):

"User Education" is what I used: that's both non-judgemental and truthful.